# Can the resultset values of prometheus alert expressions be used in annotation's description and summary?

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a prometheus alert expression of histogram summary, expression as

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(increase(event_bucket{source="current"}[5m])) by (le, mode)) > 30
```

It can produce results with various mode= such as:

> {mode="ABC"}  38.4
>
> {mode="XYZ"}  39.3

**Can I use the above result mode in my annotation description, summary to explain, for which mode i have received this alert?**
like

```
annotations:
     description: event bucket of mode - - -(whatever modes we would receive from result) - - - are greater than 30.
     summary: summary of same
```

Please guide as I am new to this.

*Thanks!!*

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
description: event bucket of mode {{ $labels.mode }} is {{ $value | printf "%.2f" }} and is greater than 30.
```

Comment: Thanks Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira. This solves the problem even I had added the similar solution with screenshot output for the same.

Comment: I thought the additional "{{ $value | printf "%.2f" }}" info could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found to answer the same with **{{ $labels }}  {{ $value }}**

```
annotations:
 description: event bucket of mode {{ $labels }} and threshold is {{ $value }} are greater than 30.
 summary: summary of same
```

Based on result those many alerts can be created
[image]

There may be several solutions exists, this I find to solve the above.

Keep learning keep sharing. Thanks